# vs 2010, Include in project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010. I have a images folder, and i am uploading an image into that folder on a button click, that is successful. But i am having a problem, what happens is that once the image is uploaded it does not get included in the project automatically, is there any work around for this.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of project are you creating? Web application, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: Do you want the images to appear in Visual Studio or on the website?

Comment: both, because i am using the image to display it in a repeater.

Comment: Update your question with all this new information - it will help you get better answers. You don't need to have the image in the project for your code to be able to find it and use it in a repeater.

Comment: I am having the same issue. The 'images' folder contains 100's of product images. When the designer adds images into 'images' folder (not using VS) then I publish the site with new code, the newly added images do not get published. When I 'Exclude' > then 'Include..' the 'images' folder, it takes over 8 minutes. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to automatically Include In Project ("automatically" as in, using the command line batches "Pre-Build", "Pre-Link" "Post-Build"). You must right-click on the file (or entire containing folder) and then select "Include In Project".